# substitute for bash "<<<" in fish

Tags: bash, fish

I have just tried using the following command in both fish and bash:

```
tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 0
```

In bash it works just fine but when I try it in fish it returns this.

```
tee /s/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightnes <<< 0                          0 < 14:20:33
Expected a string, but instead found a redirection
fish: tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightnes <<< 0
                                                          ^
```

As fish has a lot of Command Substitutions I was trying to find out how to substitute <<< but I couldn't find it listed in their tutorial:
https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions

I would be glad if someone could help me out there,

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fish shell apparantly has no support for "here strings" (like in bash). You can use:

```
echo 0 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Answer (score 6):

`<<<` is a nice way to pass a string over standard input but if you don't have it, there's always just `echo`:

```
echo 0 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```